# Unexpected Behaviour when using strtok

Tags: c, string

So I'm given a string as such:

```
Hello6World66ABC
```

Where I'm told to replace single instances of the character '6' to be two asteric characters `"**"`

And multiple instances of 6's to be two of these characters `"^^"` (Any combinations of the number 6 in a row would qualify.

I'm attempting to do this by passing through each character in a `char *`,then if I find the 6 character, I check if the next character is a 6, if not we have the first case, otherwise we have the second case (Multiple 6's).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char * str;
    int i;
    str = malloc(17);

    strcpy(str,"Hello6World66ABC");

    for(i=0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
        if(str[i] == '6') {
            if(str[i+1] != '6') {
                char * token = strtok(str,"6");
                strcpy(str,token);
                strcat(str,"**");
                printf("String is now %s\n",str);

                token = strtok(NULL,""); /*get the rest of the string*/ /* should be World66ABC */
                printf("Rest of the string is %s\n",token);
                str = (char *) realloc(str,strlen(str) + strlen(token) + 1);
                strcat(str,token);
                printf("String is now %s\n",str);
                /*    should be Hello**World66ABC    */
            }
            else {
                /*if the next characters are also (multiple ones in a row)  6's, replace it with two ^^ characters*/
                char * token = strtok(str,"6");
                token = strtok(NULL,"6");
                printf("TOKEN IS %s\n",token);

                strcpy(str,token);
                strcat(str,"^^");

                token = strtok(NULL,""); /*get the rest of the string*/ /* should be World66ABC */
                printf("Rest of the string is %s\n",token);
                str = (char *) realloc(str,strlen(str) + strlen(token) + 1);
                strcat(str,token);
                printf("String is now %s\n",str);


            }
        }
    }

    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

By the string given, My expected final string should be:

```
Hello**World^^ABC
```

However, my strtok calls don't work the way I intended.

In the second if statement, where I check `if (str[i+1] != '6')`, I'm checking if there is only a single 6, there is.

Then I call strtok and print everything before it:
it prints: `Hello**`

Which is correct
I strcat the new characters on to it which works, however, on my second strtok call, to get the rest of the string, it just doesn't work.

It instead prints:

```
"Rest of the string is *"
```

So clearly it's not getting the rest of the string, even though I set the delimiter to be an empty string.

I tried to change the delimiter to be other characters, but each result in the same output. I'm also reallocating because the string gets longer, in the first case. Also the else statement seems to never run, even though I clearly have a case where there are multiple 6's.

I'm not sure where I've gone wrong here, any ideas?

Comment: I'm not so sure `strtok` is even the right tool for the job here.

Comment: Since you are looping through each char, I see no need for `strtok` - you already know where the 6s are. Also, a better option might be to create a second string buffer to create a new string.

Comment: So, what **exactly** is your input? And why use `strtok` anyway? Also: if I read that correctly, you `strcat` the two `**` into the original string. That code looks unnecessarily blown up for that simple task. @FredLarson is right `strtok` is the wrong function.

Comment: If I create a second string buffer, copy in the actual string. go to the position of the 6's, and then how would I replace the characters?

Comment: A simple loop to parse the string char by char, outputting each until you meet a `6`, when you count the sixes until it is no longer a six. Then you output either `**` or `^^` depending on the six count, followed by the next (if any) character.

Comment: Unless you are on a RAM-limited architecture, often (if not most times) copying is better than replacing.

Comment: Weather Vane, any chance you could post a code snippet? Easier to understand that way. I get that I can count the number of times 6 appears in the string, lets say its 3 here. How would I know which 6's are multiples and which aren't.

Comment: Your approach is anyway flawed.  You cannot, in general, update the string in-place because the output of the transformation can be up to 50% larger than the input.  You will overrun the bounds of the input array if it does not have enough extra capacity to accommodate the result.

Comment: Even if you hadn't a size problem, the details of your approach just don't work.  When you `strcat()` `"**"` at the position that once held a `6`, you clobber the character after that position in the original string, and replace the following one with a string terminator.  That's what causes the specific misbehavior you asked about.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Well, I assume that's what the `realloc` call is supposed to do.

Comment: @Olaf, you're right, I missed the `realloc()`.  But the approach still doesn't work, as I already described.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Of course it does not, as I stated before you :-P (just not that clear;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested, but it shows the general idea.

```
strcpy(str,"Hello6World66ABC");

// New string will be at most 2x as long
char *new_str = calloc(strlen(str) * 2 + 1, 1);
int new_str_index = 0;

for (int i = 0; 0 != str[i]; i++) {
    // Check for 6
    if ('6' == str[i]) {
        // Check for 2nd 6
        if ('6' == str[i+1]) {
            // Add chars
            new_str[new_str_index++] = '^';
            new_str[new_str_index++] = '^';
            // Consume remaining 6s - double check this for off-by-one
            while ('6' == str[i+1]) i += 1;
        }
        else {
            // Add chars
            new_str[new_str_index++] = '*';
            new_str[new_str_index++] = '*';
       }
    }
    // No 6s, just append text
    else {
        new_str[new_str_index++] = str[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: And to copy the new_str into the original str, I'd have to realloc, and then memmove() to avoid overlap?

Comment: Yes, or I would just: `free(str); str = strdup(new_str);`.

Comment: Supposing, of course, that the original string is reallocatable.  If it is a pointer to a string literal (not the case in either posted code) then you cannot expect to successfully reallocate.  The most general solution is to return a pointer to the new string.

Answer (score 1):

OP asked for a simple way of altering the `'6'` characters in the string. If you want to write to another string instead of printing directly, I leave it to you to define the other (large enough) string, and copy the chars to that string instead of to `stdout`. But do NOT try to alter the string passed, it is doomed to fail.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sixer(char *str)
{
    int i = 0, sixes;
    while(str[i] != '\0') {
        if(str[i] == '6') {
            sixes  = 0;
            while(str[i] == '6') {
                sixes++;
                i++;
            }
            if(sixes == 1) {
                printf("**");
            }
            else {
                printf("^^");
            }
        }
        else {
            printf("%c", str[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    sixer("Hello6World66ABC");
    sixer("6");
    sixer("66666");
    return 0;
}
```

Program output

```
Hello**World^^ABC
**
^^
```